# Error "missing operand" al leer dbfs

Tags: c#

Quiero leer la tabla ventas.dbf filtrando un rango de fechas pero me arroja el error "missing operand".
Cuando lo hago con el comando

```
Cmd.CommandText = "select * from ventas where fecha>={^2021/12/18} and fecha<={^2021/12/19} and (facbol='F' or facbol='B')
```

me funciona muy bien.
Pero lo que necesito es poner las fechas con parámetros.
Lo hago de la siguiente manera pero me sale el error mencionado.
Muchas gracias de antemano por su valioso apoyo.

```
 public List<Comprobante> LeerDbfs(DateTime del, DateTime al, string directorio)
        {
            List<Comprobante> ListaComprobantes = new List<Comprobante>();
            //  DBFS
            string myOleDbConnection = "Provider = VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source = " + directorio + ";";
            using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(myOleDbConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Comprobante> myListacomprobantes = new List<Comprobante>();
                    Conn.Open();
                    using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        //Cmd.CommandText = "select * from ventas where fecha>={^2021/12/18} and fecha<={^2021/12/19} and (facbol='F' or facbol='B')";
                        string mydel = del.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        string myal = al.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        Cmd.CommandText = "select * from ventas where dtoc(fecha)>=@mydel and fecha<=@myal and (facbol='F' or facbol='B')";
                        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        Cmd.Connection = Conn;
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydel", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mydel;
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@myal", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = myal;
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Comprobante comprobante = new Comprobante();
                                    comprobante.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["fecha"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                    comprobante.TipoComprobante = reader["facbol"].ToString() == "F" ? "01" : "03";
                                    comprobante.Numero = reader["numdoc"].ToString().Trim();
                                    comprobante.Serie = reader["facbol"].ToString() + reader["numdoc"].ToString().Substring(0, 3);
                                    comprobante.Cliente = reader["apeynom"].ToString().Trim();
                                    comprobante.TipoDocumento = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ruc"].ToString().Trim()) ? "RUC" : "DNI";
                                    comprobante.NumeroDocumento = reader["ruc"].ToString() + reader["dni"].ToString().Trim();  // uno de los dos o ninguno
                                    comprobante.Importe = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["monto"].ToString());
                                    comprobante.Anulado = (bool)reader["cancelada"] ? "SI" : "NO";
                                    comprobante.Status = string.Empty;
                                    myListacomprobantes.Add(comprobante);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return myListacomprobantes;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera pero me sale el error: "OleDbParameterCollection sólo acepta objetos de tipo no null OleDbParameter, no objetos String."

```
public List<Comprobante> LeerDbfs(DateTime del, DateTime al, string directorio)
{
    List<Comprobante> ListaComprobantes = new List<Comprobante>();
    //  DBFS
    string myOleDbConnection = "Provider = VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source = " + directorio + ";";
    using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(myOleDbConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            List<Comprobante> myListacomprobantes = new List<Comprobante>();
            Conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                string mydel = del.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                string myal = al.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                Cmd.CommandText = "select * from ventas where fecha >= ? and fecha <= ? and (facbol='F' or facbol='B')";
                Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                Cmd.Connection = Conn;
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(mydel);
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(myal);
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Comprobante comprobante = new Comprobante();
                            comprobante.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["fecha"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            comprobante.TipoComprobante = reader["facbol"].ToString() == "F" ? "01" : "03";
                            comprobante.Numero = reader["numdoc"].ToString().Trim().Substring(4, 6);
                            comprobante.Serie = reader["facbol"].ToString() + reader["numdoc"].ToString().Substring(0, 3);
                            comprobante.Cliente = reader["apeynom"].ToString().Trim();
                            comprobante.TipoDocumento = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ruc"].ToString().Trim()) ? "RUC" : "DNI";
                            comprobante.NumeroDocumento = reader["ruc"].ToString() + reader["dni"].ToString().Trim();  // uno de los dos o ninguno
                            comprobante.Importe = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["monto"].ToString());
                            comprobante.Anulado = (bool)reader["cancelada"] ? "SI" : "NO";
                            comprobante.Status = string.Empty;
                            myListacomprobantes.Add(comprobante);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return myListacomprobantes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que usas `OleDbType.VarChar` en lugar de `OleDbType.Date`?

Comment: El proveedor OLE DB .NET no admite parámetros con nombre para pasar parámetros a una instrucción SQL o a un procedimiento almacenado al OleDbCommand que llama cuando CommandType se establece en Text . En este caso, se debe utilizar el marcador de posición del signo de interrogación (?). Por ejemplo:
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?  (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Pikoh, al usar OleDbType.Date me arroja el mismo error. Gracias